# I need to create an array that stores 10 integers and allows the user 3 options to manipulate the data

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the code here. The first two parts are fine & without issue.

```
using System;
namespace MyNameSpace
{
  class IntArrayDemo
  {
      static void Main()
      {
        //Declare variables
        double[] dblIntArray = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000};
        string[] strIntArray = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
        double   dblSentVal  = 0;

        //Get user input
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to view the list in numeric order. Enter 2 to view the list in reverse numeric order. Enter 3 to choose a specific position to view.");
        dblSentVal = (Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));

        if (dblSentVal == 1)
        {
            foreach(double dblInt in dblIntArray)
                Console.WriteLine(dblInt);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        else if (dblSentVal == 2)
        {
            Array.Reverse(dblIntArray);
            foreach(double dblInt in dblIntArray)
                Console.WriteLine(dblInt);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        else if (dblSentVal == 3)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < strIntArray.Length; ++k)
            {
                if (strIntArray[k] == Console.ReadLine())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Number {0} in the list is {1}", strIntArray[k], dblIntArray[k]);
                }
            }
        }   
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is with the third option here:

```
else if (dblSentVal == 3)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < strIntArray.Length; ++k)
    {
        if (strIntArray[k] == Console.ReadLine())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number {0} in the list is {1}", strIntArray[k], dblIntArray[k]);
        }
    }
}   
Console.ReadLine();
```

When executed and the third option is chosen, the program will run but in order to view, say, integer 4 in the array I am having to type the number 4, 4 times in the console like so:

4
4
4
4
Number 4 in the list is 400

I do not want this. It should be displaying "Number 4 in the list is 400" after only typing 4 once. Please help!

Comment: You should include the appropriate language tag. This makes it easier to find your question as well as changed how the syntax coloring is done. I've added the C# tag for you.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am a new user

Comment: Note that `Array.Reverse` will reverse your array in place, so after you enter 2 and then 1 you'll get the array in reverse order again.  I think what you really want is `foreach(double dbInt in dblIntArray.Reverse())` which will enumerate your array in reverse without changing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Way easier than you think:

```
else if (dblSentVal == 3)
{
    int index = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
    Console.WriteLine("Number {0} in the list is {1}", index, dblIntArray[index]);
}   
Console.ReadLine();
```

Its an array, just index into it; no loop required.

You may want to use `index-1` for the second item instead, if your users don't use 0-based arrays :)

Comment: Funny how the other answers jump to the `Console.ReadLine()` issue without even checking what the code is really doing ;)

Comment: While I agree the premise is correct; this will fail due to the OP using a different array (strIntArray).

Comment: @MetroSmurf Well he just needs to `index+1`. `strIntArray` is useless.

Comment: This seems to be the easiest solution, although @MetroSmurf method was the way I was trying to go about it. This is for an intro programming class and we have not gone over what "Parse" is yet.

Comment: @PatriceGahide care to elaborate?

Comment: `Parse` just returns the integer representation of the passed string (or throws if the input was invalid).

Comment: You could use `Convert.ToInt32` instead.

Comment: @LeFemur strIntArray just contains the actual index, stored as a string, +1. Thus, it is useless, since you can just perform the inverse operation when indexing (as I noted) or expect your users to understand that 0 is the first element, not 1.

Comment: @juharr correct. Note that it is just a wrapper for `Parse`.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET that was more for LeFemur, just forgot to tag their name.

Comment: @LeFemur Also note that you already use `Convert.ToDouble` which is just `double.Parse` in disguise. Use it again here, but for an `int` :)

Answer (score 4):

`k` is equal to 0 the first time `Console.ReadLine()` is invoked in the for loop. `k` will only be equal to 4 the 4th time in the loop.

If you want the value entered by the user to be what's read in the for loop, then pull the Console.ReadLine out of the loop:

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();
for (int k = 0; k < strIntArray.Length; ++k)
{
    if (strIntArray[k] == str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number {0} in the list is {1}", strIntArray[k], dblIntArray[k]);
    }
}
```